# POST method sends clear string. REACT -> API

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, post

I have component for SQL queries and when I want to send any query to API-server backend crash down because MySQL see empty string like a my request. My backend is working good because when I test it from **postman.exe** everything is fine. 

My component with submit is on ***localhost:3000*** and api on ***localhost:5000***.

 Here is my sending method:

```
submitData= () =>{
        const { queryFromEditor } = this.props;

        let queryFromEditorString = queryFromEditor.join(' ');
        console.log(queryFromEditorString);

       let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:5000/api/query', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            "value": queryFromEditorString,
        }));

    }
```

Here is my post method

```
app.post('/api/query', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`\n  Query input : ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
  let queryInput = JSON.stringify(Object.values(req.body));

  queryInput = queryInput.slice(1,-1);// Opravit, aby to nevypadalo tak blbě
  queryInput = queryInput.slice(1,-1);

  let queryOutput;
  db.query(queryInput, (err, result) =>{
    if(err) throw err+' : '+queryInput;

    queryOutput = result;
    console.log("\nQuery output "+ JSON.stringify(queryOutput));
    res.json(queryOutput);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was on server. 
Easy fix: add "**app.use(express.json());**"